# Getting Error in hosting angular 6 on A2hosting windows server

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular6

I am trying to deploy an angular 6 application in a2hosting windows server installed node and created express server code

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/website-name'));

app.get('/*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname)));

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, () => console.log("Running...."));
```

I used the Angular CLI to build the app for production:

> ng build -prod

[However, I receive these errors when I connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhbLv.jpg)

[Image for network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7T5J.jpg)

Comment: Try with `app.get('/', ...` without the `*`.

Comment: tried but that does not worked either

Comment: Why are you sending files at all on route `('/')`? Remove this line. If you want to serve static assets like images, put them in the `/assets` folder, that's its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by you not building to the domain you plan on hosting your files on.

`ng build --prod --bh /myWebsiteSubDomain/`

Check your networks tab and see where those http requests are going to.

Comment: what is myWebsiteSubDomain isi it root directory of my url or my domain?

Comment: if you're hosting the website on the root directory then this is not the solution. Can you provide some screenshots of your network requests? (Network tab of developer tools, reload page, hover over red requests)